# Get Index of Parsed JSON data in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swiftui

Below is the structure of my data. I'm trying to create a loop to check if an employee can perform a certain service but I could not get the employee.services to work. The JSON data is loaded into EmployeesData. I'm thinking that I need to get the index from EmployeesData but I can't seem to do it with ForEach?

```
ForEach(EmployeesData){ employee in
  //This does not work
  if(employee.services[0] == "service")
}


struct Employees: Codable, Identifiable{
  var id: UUID
  var firstname: String
  var lastname: String
  var services: [String]
  var workingStatus: String
}

//Store employee data in EmployeesData
let EmployeesData: [Employees] = load("Employees.json")

private func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
let data: Data

guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else {
        fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
}

do {
    data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
} catch {
    fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
}

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
} catch {
    fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let index = employee.services.firstIndex(where: {$0 == "service"})
```